# A Word for a Person who believes only things which are globally believed/accepted?

Tags: phrase-requests, proverbs, single-word-requests, obscure-terms

Eg. In religious belief, I only believe that marriage is only a **physical** bond. There is nothing to do with rituals. Because Globally, that is the ONLY common thing in a wedding. Rituals are totally different or even optional.

Another example is, God. He/She/It is there. It is globally accepted. But I won't believe about its physical address or shape.

Comment: My first thought was *globalist*, but Wikipedia's quite comprehensive entry on that word seems to consider it only in terms of economics.

Comment: [***Reductionism** is any of several related philosophical ideas regarding the associations between phenomena which can be described **in terms of other simpler or more fundamental phenomena**.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductionism)

Comment: Are you positing that there is some core set of beliefs that are common to everyone? And that there might be people who restrict themselves to those beliefs? To be honest, I'd be surprised if there was a term for the latter.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but the existence of god is far from globally accepted.  In the US, estimates range from 18-22% of Americans are not religious/not spiritual, with around 3% admitting to being outright atheists.  These are numbers from a couple of years ago; they are certainly higher now.  And, as countries go, the US is rather religious overall.  There are quite a few places where religion/belief in god is nearly non-existent.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that is only related to religion/religious beliefs or something more universal?  I'm not sure such a word exists because I don't think there is any belief or even fact that is universally believed/accepted.  Heck, there are still a lot of people who believe the earth is flat, so you can't even say that the earth being spherical (more or less) is a universal belief.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn not just for religion. I'm talking about general/all thoughts.

Comment: @user888379 exactly. A word for that person

Answer (score 1):

In a philosophical or theological sense you may be a [Universalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universalism)

From the above linked Wikipedia article

> Universalism is a theological and philosophical concept that some
>   ideas have universal application or applicability. A
>   community that calls itself universalist may emphasize the universal
>   principles of most religions, and accept others in an inclusive
>   manner. It is centered around the belief in a universal reconciliation
>   between humanity and the divine.

However, there seem to be various different kinds of universalism, which does sound like somewhat of a contradiction, but is related to the different theological histories.
 What all the religious universalisms have in common seems to be an effort to be inclusive (also of the people who don't belong to the particular 'universal school') But there is also **non-religious universalism** which sounds like a set of general common conceptions which most people can subscribe to. 
Perhaps at a stretch it could include your beliefs on human attraction not requiring rituals and papers.

Again from that Wikipedia article: a commentary on **non-religious universalism**

> Indeed, many Universalists may be attracted to the logic of
>   universally applicable principles, rather than any belief or dogma.
>   Human unity, solidarity, and the perceived need for a sustainable and
>   socially conscious global order are among the tendencies of
>   non-religious Universalist thought.

But it sounds like you do believe in some manner of spirituality. Perhaps your world view has similariteis with the Unitarian Universalists.

> **Unitarian Universalism (UU)** is a theologically liberal religion
>   characterized by a "free and responsible search for truth and
>   meaning".Unitarian Universalists do not share a creed; rather,
>   they are unified by their shared search for spiritual growth and by
>   the understanding that an individual's theology is a result of that
>   search and not a result of obedience to an authoritarian requirement.
>   Unitarian Universalists draw from all major world religions and
>   many different theological sources and have a wide range of beliefs
>   and practices.

Answer (score 0):

I'd describe it as:

[**Spiritual**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Spiritual) (adjective)<sub>1.2</sub> :

> (of a person) not concerned with material values or pursuits.
>
> > "They are spiritual beings, incorporeal intelligences, and they may --have their origins in personalities."

So, you are spiritualist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for:

[**Conformist**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conformist)

> A person who conforms to accepted behaviour or established practices.

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your own words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content not just dictionary spam.